# Using Custom List on SlidingMenu

Tags: android

Im trying to implement Koush's Widgets https://github.com/koush/Widgets inside of a jfeinstein10's SlidingMenu but i can figure out how to do it or if its doable

I got both working, I can add add the widgets to any activity and also got the slidingmenu with a separate xml.

Im using the example code from https://github.com/koush/Widgets as base

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what's your specific problem?

Comment: well since I'm a beginner, I'm just asking if its doable and some pointers to achieve it, or if its not i could stop playing with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i figure it out by using the examples from sliding menu using frames and some others examples from the web.
This is my fragment class where ill use Koush widgets

```
    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public class MyListFragment extends BetterListFragment  {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, View view) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, view);
    addItem("test", new ListItem(getInternal(), R.string.hello_world, 0, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
}


   }
```

This is my Base activity where i build the sliding menu

```
   public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {


    protected BetterListFragment mFrag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //set the Behind View
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            mFrag = new MyListFragment();
            t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
            t.commit();
        } else {
            mFrag = (MyListFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
        }

        //customize the SlidingMenu
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setBehindWidth(250);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
 }
  }
```

and this is my main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity   {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



   }

   }
```

Hope it helps someone else out there :)